# ¿Cómo aislar cada palabra de un documento?

Tags: c, archivo, algoritmos, hash, caracteres

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char palabra[20];
    char documento[30];
    printf("Introduzca el nombre del documento incluyendo .txt:");
    scanf("%s", &documento);
    printf("Intorduce la palabra que deseas buscar\n");
    scanf("%s", &palabra);
    printf("La palabra es: %s\n\n", palabra);
    FILE * flujo = fopen(documento, "rb");
    if(flujo == NULL) {
            perror("Error, el documento no se ha encontrado");
            return 1;

    }
    char caracter;
    while(feof(flujo) == 0){
        caracter = fgetc(flujo);
        printf("%c", caracter);
    }
    fclose(flujo);
    printf("\n Se ha leido el documento");
    return 0;
}
```

Hasta ahora lo que tengo es el código para cargar el documento de texto en el que quiero buscar y el scan para poner una palabra que este dentro de ese documento y buscarla. **El problema es como aíslo cada palabra del documento para compararla con la palabra que se ha introducido.**

Comment: ¿ Que significa `aislar` ? ¿ Con *espacios* ` ` delante y detrás ? ¿ Con cualquier cosa que no sea un *carácter* ? ¿ Como está codificado ese archivo ? ¿ ASCII ? ¿ UTF-8 ?

Comment: El archivo esta UTF-8 y con aislar me refiero a detectar los espacios para diferenciar entre palabras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

```
FILE *a = fopen("a.txt", "r");

if (a)
{
    char buffer[0xff] = "";
    while (fscanf(a, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
        printf("Leido %s\n", buffer);
    fclose(a);
}
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GewH6oQ8aar68Co4).

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tus palabras están separadas por espacios y saltos de lineas, he modificado tu código cerca del while:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   char palabra[20];
   char documento[30];
   printf("Introduzca el nombre del documento incluyendo .txt:");
   scanf("%s", &documento);
   printf("Intorduce la palabra que deseas buscar\n");
   scanf("%s", &palabra);
   printf("La palabra es: %s\n\n", palabra);
   FILE * flujo = fopen(documento, "rb");
   if(flujo == NULL) {
        perror("Error, el documento no se ha encontrado");
        return 1;
}
char caracter;
int i = 0; //Itera entre los caracteres de la palabra a buscar
int bandera=1; //Uno en caso de que los caracteres coincidadan 0 en otro caso
while(feof(flujo) == 0){
    caracter = fgetc(flujo);
    //Si el caracter es un espacio o salto de linea, revisara si 
    //hasta el momento los cararcteres coinciden con los de la 
    //palabra a buscar
    if(caracter==' ' || caracter==10) 
    {    
        i=-1; //Regresa i a estado inicial
        if(bandera) //Palabra encontrada
            printf(" <- (aqui)");
        bandera=1;
    }
    //Si el caracter no es el mismo de la palabra
    else if(caracter!=palabra[i]) 
        bandera=0;
    i++;
    printf("%c",caracter);
}    
fclose(flujo);
printf("\n Se ha leido el documento");
return 0;
}
```

Lo que se hace es comparar carácter por carácter, iterando entre cada uno de los caracteres de la palabra a buscar, y cuando encuentra que uno no coincide lo marca con la bandera en 0. Asi cuando se encuentra un espacio o un salto de linea, sabra si la palabra era o no la misma.

Saludos.♣